# Perl: How to access a hash with array values in a loop?

Tags: perl

I've defined a hash with arrays as values:

```
%myhash = ( 'key1' => [ 'key1value1', 'key1value2' ],
            'key2' => [ 'key2value1', 'key2value2' ],
            .......
            'key100' => [ 'key100value1', 'key100value2' ] );
```

How can we access the values of each key using a loop?

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
print "$myhash{'key1'}->[0]   and  $myhash{'key1'}->[1]\n";
print "$myhash{'key2'}->[0]   and  $myhash{'key2'}->[1]\n";
.......
print "$myhash{'key100'}->[0]   and  $myhash{'key100'}->[1]\n";
```

to print those two array values of each key in separate lines.

I've tried using an index in for/while loops with no success.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
%myhash = ( 'key1' => [ 'key1value1', 'key1value2' ],
            'key2' => [ 'key2value1', 'key2value2' ],
            'key3' => [ 'key3value1', 'key3value2' ] );

for my $k (sort keys %myhash)
{
    print "$myhash{$k}->[0] $myhash{$k}->[1]\n";
}
```

If the number of array elements varies:

```
for my $k (sort keys %myhash)
{
    for my $v (@{$myhash{$k}})
    {
        print "$v ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted... even when the number of array elements varies. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do not post "thank you" comments.  You express thanks by upvoting helpful answers and accepting the one that solves your problem (which you've already done).  You should take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: He have 56k, I think he knows this ^^

Comment: No, the OP has 18

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution...just for fun and maybe even more concise. Not sure if you can compress this even further:

```
print join ' ', @$_, "\n" for @myhash{sort keys %myhash};
```

Works for arbitrary long value arrays in `%myhash`.

EDIT:

As simbabque pointed out in the comments, it can indeed be further compressed. Thanks for the hint!

```
say join ' ', @$_ for @myhash{sort keys %myhash}; # requires: use feature 'say';
```

Comment: Use `say` to make it shorter. But we are not on code golf. Short is not necessarily more concise. Sometimes it's just harder to read. ;-)

Comment: Very nice thanks! No code golf, just a little bit of perl spirit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
print map {  join(" ", @{ $myhash{$_} }, "\n") } sort keys %myhash;
```

(the concise way)